# How to debug a Teams tab on iOS?

Tags: ios, windows, debugging, microsoft-teams

Is it possible de debug a Teams tab on iOS using Windows (or Mac) ? I tried the [inspect.dev](https://inspect.dev/) tool and it works perfectly for Safari but not for a Teams tab which is running in a Webview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to debug a Teams tab on iOS using Windows (or Mac) .
Using Dev Tools we can debug Teams tab in desktop and Android clients.

For reference doc: [DevTools for Microsoft Teams tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools)