# Cannot view mobile app for tab development

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I am trying to create a layout for our teams channel tab app but when running the app locally and inspecting it as a mobile device, teams throws an error that the browser is not supported.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction to develop my app for mobile use or how I can view the mobile app from the VS Code Teams Toolkit debugging tools?

[image: Chrome Error]

I have tried to run the app in chrome and in MS Edge browsers and use the inspector device emulators in both but get the same error. I have also tried connecting via my local machine's IP /the FE port 53000 and also have had no luck there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used directly my mobile device (android) with Teams App installed for debugging teams custom tab (both phone and tablet worked fine). Connect your android device to your laptop/desktop (using USB), and then on the phone:

- Enable USB debugging
- Enable "Developer Preview" in Teams options

In the desktop chrome, navigate to `chrome://inspect/devices` and you should see your device there in the list available for inspection/debugging. You could probably also connect using local WIFI (?), but I have not tried that. Also never tried that with Edge, so not sure if it works.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools#access-devtools-from-an-android-device

Comment: thanks for that, my issue from here is that I do not have an Andriod device and it doesn't seem to work the same on IOS. Any advice?

Comment: I am not sure if it's possible with iPad/iPhone. Here they guys are saying it's not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70739593/how-to-debug-a-teams-tab-on-ios